# Xamarin.Forms Entry.Focus() is not working in Android 9 and 10

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a sample Xamarin.Forms application we are trying to focus an Entry field after it becomes Visible on a Button Click

Below is the code snippet we are using to achieve above behavior I mentioned

```
void OnClick(object sender,EventArgs arg)
{
      searchEntry.IsVisible = true;
      searchEntry.Focus();
}
```

This is working fine in all iOS devices and android devices below 9 for android 9 and 10 the keypad shows up but the typed letters are not getting reflected in the Entry fields.

Can anyone have experienced the same issue before? Please let me know if there is any solution for that in the Answers section.

Comment: I could not found any issue from your code ,and it works fine on my device(Android 9.0) .So you can provide a sample which contains the issue and I will check it on my side .

Comment: Do not add a delay that is not the correct way of fixing things

Comment: @FreakyAli, Yes I agree with you, Should we report it as Bug?

Comment: @vigneshkumar try focusing first then changing the visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give device some time to process previous request.

```
(void)OnClick(object sender,EventArgs arg)
{
      searchEntry.IsVisible = true;
      await Task.Delay(500);
      searchEntry.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. This fixed my error both in Android and iOS

Comment: But Apart from workaround whether it is a bug in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: In my opinion yes, like hundreds of other things, you are facing when working deeper with Xamarin forms. On other hand it is not possible to cover all Android nad iOS distributions with mono 100%.

Comment: @Adlorem what are you even talking about?

Comment: About Xamarin. I been using it since xamarin studio.